# What is the correct way to compare 2 false statements in python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Given the sample code:

```
        if not token == '-' or token == '+':
        print token
```

The - is detected but the + is not

If I edit the code to:

```
        if not token == '-' or not token == '+':
        print token
```

Neither is detected.

Comment: @Selcuk they have the same precedence

Comment: There is also a simple `!=` operator which means `not equals`. But to do this, you need the `and` operator instead of `or` (DeMorgan's Law). However the most pythonic way is probably `if token not in '-+':`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
if token not in '-+':
```

But traditionally, put the `not` outside of some ors...

```
if not (token == '-' or token == '+'):
```